# Equivalences of a tight sequence of probability measures on $\mathbb{R}^{k}$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm reading about thightness of probability measure sequences. The definition of the book is the next:

Def. A sequence $\{\mu_{n}\}$ of probability measures on $(\mathbb{R}^{k},\mathcal{B({\mathbb{R}^{k}}})$ is tight if for every $\epsilon>0,$ there is a bounded rectangle $A$ such that $\mu_{n}(A)>1-\epsilon$ for all $n.$ Here a bounded rectangle has the form $A=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{k}: a_{i}<x_{i}\leq b_{i}, i=1,\ldots,k\}.$

I've found in other books (mostly ) the next definition:

A sequence $\{\mu_{n}\}$ of probability measures on $(\mathbb{R}^{k},\mathcal{B(\mathbb{R}^{k}})$ is thigt if for every $\epsilon>0,$ there is a compact set $K$ such that $\mu_{n}(K)>1-\epsilon$ for all $n.$

Are they equivalent definitions?

I'm trying to prove both definitions are equivalent but I'm stuck. My guess is covering $K$ with a finite collection of open rectangles which are contained in bounded rectangles and using the first definition, but I don't get any clear.

For the other direction I suppose that It is possible to approach any bounded rectangle with compact sets and to use the second definition (same idea as above) but I'm not sure.

Any kind o help is thanked in advanced.

Comment: Recall the [Heine-Borel Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem). Then if $K$ is compact, it is bounded, and hence contained in some rectangle (say, the centered cube of side length $4 \max\{\|x\|_\infty, x \in K\}$), and alternatively, if $A$ is a rectangle, it's closure is bounded and hence compact. Then use that $E \subset F \implies \mu(F) \ge \mu(E).$

Comment: Thanks @stochasticboy321. Very useul things to keep in mind.